# Second hyperlink silently removed during edit

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, images, editor

Earlier, I tried to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605339/how-to-update-colomn-on-condition-in-sql-server):

> my table Muster contain following data  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605339/how-to-update-colomn-on-condition-in-sql-server):
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fDGM.png
>
> And final output I want is
>
> [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi5GN.png
>
> How to query database to get required output

I cut the first hyperlink and used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to paste it as an image.  As a result, the second hyperlink was removed from the post!  I had to edit the entire thing in notepad.

Perhaps a point of improvement for the image inserter wizard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not a bug but by design. The OP used the wrong syntax, that is all.

Normally, you'd get links like:

```
* [link text][1]
* ![image alt text][2]

[1]: http://example.com
[2]: http://example.com/image.png
```

Note the numbered *link targets*, each coupled with a *link text* before it; images are just a special form of this syntax. The link targets are using the form `[index]: link`.

The editor removes any link target if there is no corresponding *link text*. Since the OP had used *just* the link target syntax, they were removed automatically because there were no corresponding link text for them. This allows you remove *link text* lines in the body of the text, and the editor takes care of the corresponding targets; the rest are even renumbered if you remove links in the middle of the sequence.

The editor only does this on subsequent edits, not for the initial revision; *any* edit you made would have removed these targets, but you had made one of them into a proper link already.

For next time, remove the `[index]:` prefixes first before using the toolbar buttons, or simply insert the image syntax by hand in the editor rather than use the toolbar options.

Comment: Right, looks like the OP struck the precise link target format by accident.  What's the benefit of removing unused link targets?  It's sure annoying when a guid-like URL is lost.

Comment: @Andomar: because it makes maintaining posts with several links in them far more manageable.

Comment: I'd think a "remove unused targets" hyperlink would be better for that, but your answer explains what happened.